# Application that can send files from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: files

Instead of using usb and copy my files, rebooting, go to windows and paste it, I want an application that can send files to windows from ubuntu WITHOUT INTERNET AND REBOOTING.

I'm using lubuntu 12.04 and windows xp.

Please give me solutions of applications like how i described it.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: You can paste the files to your Windows C: drive from ubuntu, can't you?

Comment: There is no such application. That function to copy files to and from the Windows partition is built into Ubuntu already.

Answer (score 3):

Just mount your windows drive in your Linux system.

1. Find out which drive (partition) you are interested in. You can do this by running  `sudo lsblk -f` which will list all available partitions and `grep`ing for `ntfs`. For example, on my system, I get

   ```
   sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE | grep ntfs
   ├─sda2 ntfs     14.7G
   ├─sda3 ntfs     78.1G
   ```

   From the output above I know that it's either `sda2` or sda3`. In this case, I know that the drive I am after is the 78G one so I need`sda3`. In all of the instructions below, make sure to replace`sda3` with whatever you get for this step.
2. Create a mount point for the partition

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/windows
   ```
3. Mount the drive

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/windows
   ```

   You should now be able to copy things to/from your drive just like any other location on your system.
4. Make it happen automatically.

   Edit `/etc/fstab` and add this line (as always, change `sda3` to whatever you found in step 1):

   ```
    /dev/sda3  /media/windows ntfs rw,errors=remount-ro    0   0
   ```

That's it, the drive will now be mounted automatically at `/media/windows` and you can use it just like any other directory.

Comment: That's one solution. I had a sort of application that makes an partition to put files in so you can send files between ubuntu and windows. Plus, i have windows xp.

Comment: @Lemmeask windows XP shouldn't make any difference. At worst, you should look for a `vfat` rather than `ntfs` partition. The idea is the same, you just need to mount the partition to your Linux system and you can then copy freely. You should also be able to do this through the file manager, isn't there an icon on the left hand pane showing your windows partition?

Comment: But this app you don't need to go through all these files and stuff. You just put your file in and finish. Sorry, for "fighting back".

Comment: @Lemmeask Don't worry about "fighting back", it's your question and you should get an answer you like :). Did you try mounting the drive graphically from your file manager as I suggested? If that's not possible, you only need to do the things I describe here _once_ and then forget about it. It's not something you need to do every time you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your windows partition directly in Ubuntu.
Either by your file explorer or by using the mount command.
Here you go for more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

To mount your Windows partition (or any other attached partition for that matter!) is super easy with the file explorer (which you can access by hitting the Super key + typing files + hitting enter after files are displayed). The file manager will start.

As the linked help page notes: "Simply look in the left pane of the file manager for the partition you wish to mount and click on it - it will be mounted and its contents will show up in the main pane". It's really that easy. After this you have the Windows partition working just like any other.

Comment: That's one solution. I had a sort of application that makes an partition to put files in so you can send files between ubuntu and windows. Plus, i have windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

You can read ntfs partitions directly from Ubuntu, using `ntfs-3g`.
Create the folder where you want to mount the windows partition:

```
mkdir ~/my_win
```

then type in the command to mount the partition:

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sda1  ~/my_win
```

where /dev/sda1 is your partition window

Type `man ntfs-3g` for more help.

Comment: That's one solution. I had a sort of application that makes an partition to put files in so you can send files between ubuntu and windows. Plus, i have windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a partition as @terdon said is the best way. Most effient and fast.

If you want a cloud solution, personally i really like [Drop Box](https://www.dropbox.com/)

Comment: Does it use internet? I don't want to on internet on my windows xp which is outdated and not anymore supported. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Yes, its a cloud solution. You will host files on private server from Dropbox. So do the Partition, or make a LAN server

Comment: But that means my windows xp is online and i don't want it. Its very fragile to viruses and malware. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always, if you want something easy to do without reboot or internet connect, save your files on external HD...

Answer (score -1):

[Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) is a free application to read ext filesystems from Windows. There's also another free application, called [Paragon Extfs](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/), which is able to read and write files on ext partitions, but it's known to break some Linux installations.

Comment: The OP wants to know about writing files the other way around.

Comment: @Jobin I don't think so. It's pretty easy to use NTFS partitions in Ubuntu, while Windows doesn't even recognize filesystem of ext partitions.

Comment: I mean the OP wants to write on an NTFS partition from ubuntu, which doesn't required third-party applications.

Comment: It may be easy but that's what the OP is asking: "I want an application that can send files to windows from ubuntu".